# Bootstrap col wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a question about Bootstrap's `col` class.
I have this section of DOM:

```
    <div class="participant col-xl-6 col-12">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="select-participant container">
                            <div class="row">
                                // HERE
                                <input class="participant-name col search-input" placeholder="Choose user" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.userName}/>
                                <div class="participants-dropdown-button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="./images/small-arrow-down.svg" />
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In this example, the `input` that has the `col` class pushes the `div` with the `img` all the way to the right, and they line up on the same, but the upper parent uses `col-xl-6`.
In this other example:

```
            <div class="date-slider col-xl-4 col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="container date-picker-container">
                            <div class="row">
                                //HERE
                                <input class="date-range col" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.props.initialValue}/>
                                <div class="date-picker-small-button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="./images/small-arrow-down.svg" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the parent is `col-xl-4`, and the `input`s width is 100% of the parent, and the `img` is being pushed on the next row, and what I want is to have it on the same row as the `input`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Read about the [grid classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). It's `container`>`row`>`col-*`. Don't put elements other than `.col-*` directly in `.row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using those classes in a wrong way. The correct way is:

First `container` then a div with the class `row` inside that container and then a column (`col-*`) inside the row. All of your content then needs to go into the column (or one of the columns if you have several).

Also, **never** nest a `.container` inside another `.container`. At least, not directly.

Also very important: **Never use a row without at least one column inside!**

Bootstrap rows and columns are designed to work together. Never use the one without the other.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/